# Problems integrating Jenkins and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I am getting the next error:

```
java]Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test1\workspace
$ hg clone --rev default --noupdate ssh://locahost/*/test1 "C:\Program Files  (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test1\workspace"
remote: Unable to open connection:
remote: Host does not existabort: no suitable response from remote hg!
ERROR: Failed to clone ssh://locahost/*/test1
ERROR: Failed to clone ssh://locahost/*/test1
Finished: FAILURE
```

In mercurial pluging from the jenkins console I have used

`Repository URL: ssh://locahost/*/test1`

`The rest options are in default`

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a typo? locahost vs. localhost...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a typo "locahost" vs "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have a `*` character in your path to the remote repository, but that seems likely to be the culprit for this particular error (it generates similar errors against my own hg server).

Comment: Then could I write somethintg like Repository URL: ssh://locahost/test1 because I am pointing to a project which is in my machine. This is the very first time I am using jenkins

Comment: Jenkins will have to clone the repository somewhere. If your machine is a typical developer workstation, that's probably not a good place to pull it from -- you want to put it up on some server where Jenkins can easily (and always) get to it.